# Weak topology is weaker than *any* normed topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be an infinite-dimensional, real, separable Hilbert space and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_X$ **any** norm on $H$. Is it true that the weak topology on $H$ is always weaker than the norm topology induced by $\Vert \cdot \Vert_X$?

If the weak topology and the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_X$-topology are comparable then this is true: Since $H$ is reflexive, by Banach-Alaoglu the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_X$-unit ball is compact in the weak topology, but (by the Riesz-Lemma) not in the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_X$-topology. However, it is not clear that the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_X$-topology and the weak topology are comparable i.e. that one is contained in the other.

Equivalently: Is any functional of the form $\langle \cdot, f \rangle: H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f \in H$ continuous w.r.t. the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_X$-topology i.e. is it true that for any sequence $(h_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty} \subseteq H$ s.t. $\Vert h_n \Vert_X \rightarrow 0$ we have $\langle h_n, f \rangle \rightarrow 0$?

If this is not the case (which I would guess) I would appreciate an explicit counter example.

Comment: @postmortes It is the weakest topology making every *bounded* linear functional continuous, but if you change the norm then you change which functionals are bounded.

Comment: Exactly, my issue is when $\Vert \cdot \Vert_X$ is weaker than $\Vert \cdot \Vert_H$.

Comment: @postmortes If you give H the norm topology, then all bounded linear functionals are continuous. But when you change the norm, you change which functionals are bounded. The weak topology *for a fixed norm* is the weakest topology making all the bounded linear functionals continuous, but a different norm will have different bounded linear functionals. If you think your answer is correct, try writing it up formally, but you'll quickly discover how it is flawed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, certainly not.  If you're putting a new norm on $H$, that means all you know about $H$ is its vector space structure, so you can do practically anything with a new norm.  For instance, let $(x_n)$ be any sequence of linearly independent vectors in $H$ that does not converge weakly and let $(y_n)$ be any sequence of linearly independent vectors that does converge with respect to the Hilbert space norm.  Then there is a vector space isomorphism $T:H\to H$ such that $T(x_n)=y_n$.  Pulling back the Hilbert space norm along $T$ gives a new norm on $H$ (even a norm that makes $T$ a Hilbert space!) with respect to which $(x_n)$ converges.  Since $(x_n)$ does not converge weakly, this means the norm topology is not stronger than the weak topology.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another simple counterexample: Take $H=L^2(0,1)$ and  set $\|u\|_X:=\|u\|_{L^1(0,1)}$. Take $f\in L^2(0,1)$. If $u\mapsto \int_0^1 uf \ dx$ would be continuous wrt to the $L^1$-norm then $f\in L^\infty(0,1)$ would follow.